# C++ variadic template: typeid of it, way to optimize

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

So, I learn variadic templates and usage of it. Now I made that code below. The question is does some other methode exist for getting type of "Params" without any arrays or inilialized_list?

```
template<class Type, class... Params>
void InsertInVector(std::vector<Type>& v, const Params&... params)
{
    const auto variadic = {typeid(Params).name()...};
    if (typeid(Type).name() != *variadic.begin())
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("TYPES ARE NOT THE SAME!");
        return;
    }
    v.insert(v.end(), {params...});
}
```

Comment: `std::is_same_v` comes to mind.

Comment: There are two variants what the compiler respond:
1) if I use std::is_same_v<Type, Params>: 'Params': parameter pack must be explained in this context
2) if I use std::is_same_v<Type, Params...>: 'std::is_same_v': to many template arguments and type 'unknown-type' unexpected

Comment: @EventGraph [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72311361/65863) shows how to apply `Params` to `std::is_convertible_v` (the same can be done with `std::is_same_v`, but `std::is_convertible_v` makes more sense in your case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++17 and later, you can do something like this:

```
template<class Type, class... Params>
void InsertInVector(std::vector<Type>& v, const Params&... params) {
  static_assert((std::is_convertible_v<Params, Type> && ...));
  v.insert(v.end(), {params});
}
```

Comment: Yeah, It resolves my problem. Thanks!